# How to use `bokeh.models.expressions`

Tags: python, bokeh

In bokeh 0.13.0, how to use expression to calculate a column value from another of a ColumnDataSource?

According to the [document](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/expressions.html), I should be able to do something like the following:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import expr

ds = ColumnDataSource(data={'a':[1,2,3]})
plot.circle(x='a', y=expr('a+1'), size=20, source=ds)
```

But this does not work.

They say "`...will be computed ... using a ColumnDataSource as input`". Unfortunately there is no any example showing how to use this `input`.